# Sonar - Categorization Plugin

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm looking for a Sonar plugin that will let me categorize all the projects I have into groups. So, for example, instead of the classic view, I'd have:

Group A:

- Project A
- Project B

Group B:

- Project C
- Project D

I made a quick test of the Sonar Views plugin, however, it doesn't really suit my needs, since it aggregates metrics by group and doesn't offer an actual drill-down.

Does anyone have any options?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: From what I understand, the Views plugin should suit your needs.
Indeed, you can group projects, display them as filters (tables) on dashboards, drill-down, etc. Could you please elaborate on your needs?

Comment: Hello David, we're looking for a different kind of drill down.
    
Global View -> Select View -> Choose from project list -> View project dashboard.

What we're getting is:

View -> Aggregated Metrics -> Selected Metric -> Project Selection.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it you who asked the question directly through the SonarSource support mailing-list?